# Orthogonal matrix and orthonormal columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that the columns of orthogonal matrix are always orthonormal.
Hint: $A^TA=I$

Can't really get even started, I thought that it has to be orthonormal since the result is $I$ and not only a diagonal matrix with other numbers in them?

Comment: Say $\delta_{i,j}$ is the $(i,j)$-th component of $I$. What is the $i$ column times the $j$  column: $a_i^T a_j =??$

Comment: First thing is to write what it means for a column to be orthonormal. Take the column to be a vector, whose entries are those of the column, e.g. $v^1$ from column should be thought of as $v^1=(A_{11}, A_{21},\ldots, A_{n1})^T$. In general take $v^i=(A_{1i}, A_{2i},\ldots, A_{ni})^T$. Now take a dot product between say $v^i$ and $v^j$ and compare it to $(A^TA)_{ij}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix}
{v_1}  &  {v_2} ... & {v_n}   \\
 \end{bmatrix}$  as built from column vectors  and making computation $A^TA$ (which we know is equal $I$) gives result:

$\begin{bmatrix}
{v_1}^T\\
{v_2}^T\\
... \\
{v_n}^T\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
{v_1} &  {v_2} &   ...& {v_n}\\
 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
{v_1}^T{v_1} &  {v_1}^T{v_2} &   ...& {v_1}^T{v_n}\\
{v_2}^T{v_1} &  {v_2}^T{v_2}&   ...&{v_2}^T{v_n}\\
... & .... & ... &.... \\
{v_n}^T{v_1}& {v_n}^T{v_2} &  ... &    {v_n}^T{v_n}\\
\end{bmatrix}$ =$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 & ... &0\\
0 &  1 & ... &0\\
... & .... & ...&....  \\
0 &  0 & ...& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

what gives wanted interpretation.