# Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix such that $A^TA = I_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I explain that the rows of $A$ are unit vectors orthogonal to each other in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I genuinely don't know where to start. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: that's called an orthogonal matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)

Comment: Hint: the elements of $AA^T$ are scalar products of the rows of $A$, and $AA^TA=A$, and $A$ is regular.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028990/orthogonal-matrix-and-orthonormal-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orthogonal matrix and orthonormal columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028990/orthogonal-matrix-and-orthonormal-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Writing the matrix as two row vectors $r_0,r_1$, the elements of the matrix $A^TA$ are

$$\begin{pmatrix}r_0r_0^T&r_0r_1^T\\r_1r_0^T&r_1r_1^T\end{pmatrix},$$ which are dot products. Conclude.

Comment: Actually, it's just slightly more complicated: one has to consider $AA^T$ to get scalar products of rows. But it's easy to prove first that $AA^T=I_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, the first thing that you do is to compute $A^TA$; the second one is to see what it means to say that $A^TA=\operatorname{Id}_2$. You will see that it means three things:

1. The first column has norm $1$;
2. The second column has norm $1$;
3. The columns ar orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since A is a $2\times 2$ matrix, one way to do this is brute force:

$$A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^TA= \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d \\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 +b^2 & ac + bd \\
ca +db & c^2 +d^2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = I_2$$

From there, you can conclude about $a^2+b^2$,$c^2+d^2$ and $ac+bd$

Comment: Actually you have written $AA^T$.