# Why does an orthogonal matrix have the property $Q^T Q = Q Q^T = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to Wikipedia, an orthogonal matrix is a square matrix whose columns and rows are orthonormal vectors. It also says that this definition is equivalent to saying that an orthogonal matrix $Q$ is a matrix for which $Q^T Q = Q Q^T = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Why are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: If you write out matrix multiplication, it turns out that you’re computing a bunch of dot products of the columns of $Q$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028990/orthogonal-matrix-and-orthonormal-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why, if a matrix $Q$ is orthogonal, then $Q^T Q = I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766669/why-if-a-matrix-q-is-orthogonal-then-qt-q-i)

Answer (score 2):

The $(i,j)$ entry of $Q^{T}Q$ is the dot product of the $i$-th column of $Q$ with the $j$-th column of $Q$. Since $Q$ is orthogonal, these will be $0$ when $i\neq j$, and $1$ when $i=j$ (because the columns are unit vectors). Therefore $Q^{T}Q$ has ones on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else, so it's the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As pwerth noted, in the product $Q^\top Q$, the $(i,j)$-entry is simply the inner product of the $i$-th column of $Q$ with the $j$-th column. It is worth noting however that this implies that $QQ^\top$ is *also* the identity. This is because when a square matrix has a left-inverse, this left-inverse is immediately a right-inverse also.

The reason why this is interesting is because this makes a big use of the finite-dimensionality of the vector space we work over (in this case, $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n$ the size of $Q$). For more details, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i?noredirect=1&lq=1), where you'll also find a counterexample in the infinite dimensional case.